# How to remove all special characters from a column name string using regular expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

I want to remove all the special characters like $, %, #, etc from the column name of my table in SQL Server 2018.
how to do it with the help of regular expressions?

If the value in my column is "S$d#@gh", the output should be -- "Sdgh"

Thank you.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have regular expressions.... you can try a replace for each char you want to remove. Or you could write a CLR function.

Comment: Which SQL Server version do you use?

Comment: @Zhorov I use sql server 2018

Comment: @sweety It's probably the version of SQL Management Studio (a client tool). Execute `SELECT @@VERSION` to get system and build information for the current installation of SQL Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(400)='S$d#@gh'
DECLARE @expres  VARCHAR(50) = '%[~,@,#,$,%,&,*,(,),.,!]%'

WHILE PATINDEX( @expres, @str ) > 0
SET @str = Replace(REPLACE( @str, SUBSTRING( @str, PATINDEX( @expres, @str ), 1 ),''),'-',' ')
SELECT @str
```

You can Create a **SCALAR FUNCTION** & pass this Column

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Remove_SpecialCharacters( @str VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @expres  VARCHAR(50) = '%[~,@,#,$,%,&,*,(,),.,!]%'

WHILE PATINDEX( @expres, @str ) > 0
SET @str = Replace(REPLACE( @str, SUBSTRING( @str, PATINDEX( @expres, @str ), 1 ),''),'-',' ')
RETURN @str
END
```

O/P

```
SELECT dbo.Remove_SpecialCharacters(COLUMNNAME),* FROM TABLENAME
```

Comment: how to use it for all the values in column studentName?

Comment: @sweety - Plz Check Now

Comment: not working with '

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server now supports [`translate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  This allows you to do:

```
select replace(translate(column, ',~@#$%&*().!', replace(' ', 12)), ' ', '')
```

The only trick is that the replacement string of spaces needs to be exactly the same length as the characters you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link, this one worked for me for a similar problem where I needed to remove alphabetical characters and special characters so I was left with only numbers.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-remove-characters-special-symbol-from-string-using-sql-function

```
Create function [dbo].[RemoveCharSpecialSymbolValue](@str varchar(500))  
returns varchar(500)  
begin  
declare @startingIndex int  
set @startingIndex=0  
while 1=1  
begin  
set @startingIndex= patindex('%[^0-9.]%',@str)  
if @startingIndex <> 0  
begin  
set @str = replace(@str,substring(@str,@startingIndex,1),'')  
end  
else break;  
end  
return @str  
end
```

Then use @Thiyagu Select Function(Column) solution

Answer (score 0):

First replace all unwanted characters with a single unwanted character, then replace that with a blank:

```
select replace(translate('foo$#@bar', '$#@', '$$$'), '$', '')
```

Output:

```
foobar
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/104116).

Answer (score 0):

I have used another function. Negation of normal number and uppercase and lower-case letters.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RemoveSpecialCharacters( @str VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @expres  VARCHAR(max) = '%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%'

WHILE PATINDEX( @expres, @str ) > 0
SET @str = Replace(REPLACE( @str, SUBSTRING( @str, PATINDEX( @expres, @str ), 1 ),''),'-',' ')
RETURN @str
END
```